# Why navbar-right doesn't work neither float right

Tags: html

The navbar-right doesn't work and I looked over other questions with the same problem but couldn't find a way to make it function. I even tried float right on the li elements but doesn't work.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-transparent fixed-top">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div id="nav-content" class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto navbar-right">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="view" class="full-page-cover"></div>
```

Comment: This is going to be very difficult to answer without seeing your css code at the top of the page. Could you please paste it in your question? I expect it is a css problem.

Comment: Do you load all the needed css scripts and js?

Comment: a have no css related to the navbar, just css for the full background cover.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/xameqozofu/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you're using bootstrap for this, If what you want is to align the nav bar to the right most of the page, you should change the `<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto navbar-right">`  to `<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto navbar-right">`. In bootstrap mr-auto adds margin to the right of an element and ml-auto adds margin to the left of an element.

So the final code should be,

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-transparent fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div id="nav-content" class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto navbar-right">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div id="view" class="full-page-cover"></div>
```